# Gradle multi project builds, must plugins be applied in children projects' build.gradle files also?

Tags: gradle

If I have a multi-project build and in the parent *build.gradle* file, I declare the statement `apply plugin: 'java'`, and I also wish to apply this to all the children projects also, is that enough or do I also have to have this declaration in all the children build.gradle files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it is not enough.

Calling `apply` will only apply the plugin (script or binary) to the specific project that calls the method. However, you will not need to create a `build.gradle` file for each subproject, since you can access them in your root `build.gradle` file:

```
// for a specific (sub-)project
project(':sub1') {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}

// for all subprojects
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}

// for all projects
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}
```